# How can I build a circuit to drive a 12V solenoid from a 3V source, so up 3V to 12V by storing in capacitors, charge and discharge cycles?

Tags: dc, solenoid, storage

No electronics background, noob, but I want to drive a small solenoid to cycle it everytime I push a button.

I wanted to use 2 AA batteries in series as they fit the size of my project well. I will use the solenoid just to hit a fixed part and generate a small noise, like a knocker.

Comment: *no electronics background* and *How can I build a circuit* by finding an example made and designed by someone else and **exactly** rebuild that or have someone design it for you but even then you **will** struggle with some of the details. Also I advise **not** to mention anything about **how** (you think) it should be done (dis/charge capacitors), just describe what you're trying to achieve (you mostly covered that). Maybe a 3 V to 24 V DCDC converter module would do the job. How much current does the selenoid need?

Comment: What time intervals are involved? Can you tolerate a delay between the button press and the solenoid actuation? AA batteries are a poor choice, but you might be able to work it by only generating the 24V when the button is pushed (so no battery drain on standby). Must you use a 24V solenoid?

Comment: Unwind the solenoid, count the turns, and re-wind with 1/8 the turns in wire sqrt(8) times the diameter. You now have a 3V solenoid.

Comment: Thanks for replies. @henros it would need to be immediate, push the button and react like a trigger, I can change to a 12V solenoid instead. Yes only need the 12V when pushed so to create a quick movement, after the solenoid re-arms to original position, like a "clack"..

Comment: no electronics background, buy a boost converter module for $3 and enjoy quick success. (after slow shipping)

Comment: Where are you located? I'd go to Pololu.com in the US and get a boost converter. They have some with Enable pins. Find one that will boost as needed, and drive the Enable signal when you want to energize the solenoid.

Answer (score 1):

Your solenoid might not be the best tool for the job (a 5V solenoid may work as-is* and a 12V solenoid would draw less current from your AA batteries), but if you absolutely want to hack something together to make the pair work, here is what you can do:

- If you don't easily have access to other solenoids but you don't mind hacking this one: the force of a solenoid is proportional to the number of turns and the current going through them, therefore let's rewind it with the same number of turns and the same current, but at 3V. Count the number of turns of the coil as you unwind it (and make a note of the direction of the turns!), then measure the total length of wire. Measure its resistance. Divide the resistance by the length, and refer yourself to AWG gauge wire charts to get what gauge the wire is. Then, buy/find some wire which either has 8 times less resistance, or which has sqrt(8)=2.83 less copper radius. Re-wind the solenoid core with the same direction,and the same number of turns.
- If you don't easily have access to toher solenoids and you don't want to bother (and you don't mind the additional volume), try buying one of these cheap step-up/"boost" modules which have in/out ranges including your 3V in, 24V out. THe current rating must be higher than that of your solenoid (if you're not sure, measure with an ampmeter). One major drawback of this method is that the module will draw about 10 times (8 times for power conservation, a bit more for non-ideal efficiency) more current than what the solenoid needs from your batteries. This will kill your batteries quickly, so you'll have to think about the battery life you need. This might in fact not work at all, since AA batteries have around 0.15Ohm internal resistance, so depending on the current required the input voltage may sag below the minimum input voltage of your module (or might decrease its efficiency, eventually having the same effect).

Those are just ideas, time to explore!

*: Look for the minimum pull-in and release voltages in the datasheet of your solenoid, these are the values you need to guarantee

Comment: you could re-use the original wire just doubled up twice (so 4 strands in parallel where there was originally a single strand)

Comment: Yes but generally you don't have enough length in the product to wind twice, and it's generally small gauge magnet wire. Higher gauges are easier to find, if the OP's lucky he/she might get away with classic AWG28 from wrapping wires.

Comment: You will only need 1/4 of the turns (per parallel wire) if you re-wind it with 4 strands in parallel.

Comment: 4 strands in parallel give you 1/4th of the resistance, enabling you a fourth of the voltage for the same current - but only if the number of turns stays constant. 1/4 of the turns with 4 strands in parallel give you exactly the same force as the original solenoid, since N*i is the same... You would need to have 8 wires of the same gauge in parallel with the same number of turns to get the same force at 3V than you have at 24V.

Comment: Thank you all for teh suggestions! I will try with a boost. I tried with 4 AA's at 6V and a a 6V solenoid and it worked but I need more force so a 12V solenoid. Does anyone have a boost diagram/circuit to share, I wanted to built it myself?

Comment: Voltage has little to do with the force of the solenoid. It's the current, the number of turns and the magnetic circuit which give you the amount of force. 
I highly discourage you to build a boost circuit yourself if you're a beginner, especially when it's going to cost you more in  components than buying one online. Most of those you can use range from 1$ to 10$.